# How does ATLAS tuning work?

Tags: linear-algebra, atlas

It's fairly well-known that ATLAS uses "blocking" or "tiling" versions of matrix computation algorithms, which substantially improve performance.

It also appears that ATLAS has some [architectural defaults](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#WhyDef), which have been computed manually. And it's possible to do a search to determine other values for `NB` (a `#define` macro which I believe stands for number of blocks).

But how does it work? How are the values determined? Do the algorithms just run a bunch of times with different values, Monte Carlo style, until some kind of optimum is found?

Here's a hypothetical, too. Let's say you copied a blocked ATLAS algorithm into C++ templates and had a 128-bit rational type. Could you derive `NB` for the rational version of the algorithm in some way from an ATLAS-tuned `NB` value from the double version of the algorithm?